# Is it possible to clone a Git repository from the unsecured server in visual studio 2017?

Tags: git

If yes, Please suggest how can I achieve this.

I tried this via Manage Connections -> Local Git Repositories -> Clone. But it says "not valid: is this a git repository?".
It's working fine on my Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Check your proxy server, will it allow you to access unsecured git repo

Comment: Yes, it is. It's working fine for visual studio 2015.

Comment: if so, then check with configurations

Comment: Check this out https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/clone